# This script isn't running, is there a missing function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

So i have this script I've managed to repair, but there seems to be a function missing. Can anyone figure out what's wrong with it? Here's part of it, as it's too long to be able to post.

```
"use strict";

 $ (function() {

  var CLIENT_ID = '[CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      API_KEY = "[API_KEY",
      SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
      PER_PAGE = 50,
      DELAY_TIME = 500,
      DEBUG_ENABLED = false,
      PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH = 305,
      I18N = { en: {} };

  I18N.default = I18N.en;

  I18N.en.register_button_name = 'Register';
  I18N.en.dislike_button_name = 'Dislike';

  var debug = function(msg) {
    if (DEBUG_ENABLED) console.log(msg);
  };

  var getChannelURI = function() {
    var re = /youtube\.com\/(user|channel|c)\/([^\/]+)/,
        m;
    var channelId = "$"('meta[itemprop=channelId]').attr('content');
    debug(channelId);
    if (channelId) {
      return channelId;
    }
    channelId = "$"('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content');
    if (channelId) {
      return channelId.match(re)[2];
    }
  };
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a function missing? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Also the quotes around `$` are wrong, you're probably getting errors about that.

Comment: it returns an "undefined" error, and it seems to be to do with the $ sign right at the top near "function".  if i enclose the $ sign in speechmarks it becomes defined, but when i run the script it says "$ is not a function"

Comment: what do you think i should do? sorry i'm a noob at coding

Comment: The brackets aren't balanced. You have no `}` for the first `{` and no `)` for the first `(`.

Comment: It should be `channelId = $('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content');`

Comment: `$` is jQuery, you need to load the jQuery library before this if you're getting errors saying it's not a function.

Comment: thanks for answering, how do i load the jQuery library?

Comment: @Barmar, i've loaded the JQuery library using <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>, but it returns the error "unexpected token <". any ideas?

Comment: That needs to be in the HTML file that loads the above script, it shouldn't be in the `.js` file.

Comment: ok thanks, would you mind showing me how to do that please? I've never done this before

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the core issue with the script. It needs JQuery to run, but every possible way of loading or injecting JQuery fails because it "violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". This is because the script uses remote code to run, and it gets automatically blocked by Chrome's CSP. The only workaround I can see is to run the script on firefox, and since CSP can be disabled in firefox, I can then use jQuery.noConflict(); in the javascript window to allow JQuery to run in the script, and then use a separate command to inject it into the script.